# TensorFlow Same Model returning different results in Colab and local

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, sequential

I'm running the same code on Colab and on local (python3 in terminal) and getting very different results.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./my_saved_model')
inputs = pd.read_csv('./inputs.csv', index_col=0)
print(model.predict(inputs))
```

- './inputs.csv' is a single-row pandas dataframe containing input data
- './my_saved_model' is a dense sequential model

For Colab, I copied these files into the local notebook directory. `tf.__version__` is 2.5.0 on local terminal and 2.7.0 in Colab.

On Colab, the print output is `array([[0.00000000e+00]], dtype=float32)`, which seems incorrect, and on local terminal, the print output is `array([[0.447962]], dtype=float32)`, which seems correct. I've tried other input data rows, and each time Colab incorrectly returns either 0 or 1 exactly while local terminal returns correctly a value between 0 and 1.

I can't figure out why this is happening, other than the possibility that the tensorflow version is not backward-compatible.

Here's the model summary, in case it helps:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
- - -  
normalization_3 (Normalizati (None, 101)               203       
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 102  
- - -     
Total params: 305
Trainable params: 102
Non-trainable params: 203
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed that the tensorflow version is what is causing the error. I added `pip install tensorflow==2.5.0` to the colab (even though it's [not advised](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tensorflow_version.ipynb)), and everything worked as properly.

Very strange that tensorflow 2.x doesn't support backward compatibility.